# Gmail puts shared Uri as a "to" receiver field

Tags: android, uri, share, android-fileprovider

I was trying to use following piece of code from this [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharing-content-between-android-apps-2e6db9d1368b) to share files from my own app to other application like Gmail.

```
File imageFile = ...;
Uri uriToImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
    context, FILES_AUTHORITY, imageFile);
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
  .setStream(uriToImage)
  .getIntent();
// Provide read access
shareIntent.setData(uriToImage);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Correct `Uri` was provided. File was attached in a new email. But it is unlikely to work properly as Gmail put the `Uri` in "to" receiver field! I want to know what the problem is.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Delete this line:

```
shareIntent.setData(uriToImage);
```

Comment: Without this line of code, no appropriate apps are shown for sharing.

Comment: @Nava: Add a call to `setType()` on the `Builder`, providing the MIME type associated with your stream. In the end, you want an `Intent` with `ACTION_SEND`, the MIME type, and an `EXTRA_STREAM` extra (which contains your `Uri`).